# Are Hagrid's parents dead?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

I have just re-watched the *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* film for the third time and I asked myself if Hagrid's parents are dead.

**So, are they alive or aren't they?**

Comment: Also, off the top of my head, I can confirm that in the movies, Hagrid does tell us that his father is dead, this we learn in the film version of *The Goblet of Fire*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, they're both dead

In *Goblet of Fire*, Hagrid reveals to Madame Maxime that his father died shortly after he began at Hogwarts:

> Tiny little bloke, my dad was. By the time I was six I could lift him up an' put him on top o' the dresser if he annoyed me. Used ter make him  laugh..." Hagrid's deep voice broke. Madame Maxime was listening, motionless, apparently staring at the silvery fountain. "Dad raised me... but he died, o' course, jus' after I started school.
>
> <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 23: "The Yule Ball"</sup>

And in *Order of the Phoenix* he learned of his mother's death, some years prior:

> "Did you... was there any sign of... did you hear anything about your... your... mother while you were there?" Hagrid's unobscured eye rested upon her and Hermione looked rather scared.
>
> "I'm sorry... I... forget it -"
>
> "Dead," Hagrid grunted. "Died years ago. They told me."
>
> <sup>*Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 20: "Hagrid's Tale"</sup>

This is also stated or implied in the films, if that's important to you:

- As Au101 notes in a comment on the question, Hagrid's conversation with Madame Maxime in the *Goblet of Fire* film is more-or-less intact, including the revelation that Mr. Hagrid died while his son was in school:

  > **Hagrid:** He was a tiny little fella, my dad. I could pick him up with one hand by the age of six and put him up on the dresser. And then he died when I was still in school.
  >
  > <sup>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* (2005)</sup>
- While it isn't stated outright, Hagrid does imply in *Order of the Phoenix* that Grawp's mother - and therefore his mother - is dead (emphasis mine):

  > **Hagrid:** I couldn't leave [Grawp], because...because he's my brother.
  >
  > **Ron:** Blimey.
  >
  > **Hagrid:** Well, half brother, really.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > **Hagrid:** You will look after him, won't you? **I'm the only family he's got**.
  >
  > <sup>*Order of the Phoenix (2007)*</sup>

Comment: actually, the logic on that last assertion seems a bit shakey.  is it ever said anywhere that Hagrid and Grawp have the same mother?

Comment: @Michael In the book, yes. In the context of the films I don't believe it's said explicitly, but given that Grawp is about six times as tall as Hagrid, it seems very doubtful that he's a half-giant, meaning they necessarily share a mother

Answer (score 4):

Both of Hagrids parents are in fact deceased.

Hagrid tells us his father died early in his schooling career, and didnt live long enough to see him expelled.

> ‘Tha’ was taken jus’ after I got inter Hogwarts,’ said Hagrid,
>   croakily. ‘Dad was dead chuffed ... thought I migh’ not be a
>   wizard, see, ’cos me mum ... well, anyway. ‘Course, I never was
>   great shakes at magic, really ... but at least he never saw me
>   expelled. Died, see, in me second year ...

While his mother after abandoning him and his father died sometime later after at least having Hagrids half brother.

> ‘Did you ... was there any sign of ... did you hear anything about
>   your ... your ... mother while you were there?’ Hagrid’s unobscured
>   eye rested upon her and Hermione looked rather scared. ‘I’m sorry ...
>   I ... forget it –’ ‘Dead,’ Hagrid grunted. ‘Died years ago. They told
>   me.’